# Find min and max of a column given an ordered index in Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a vector and I add his indexes like it follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
## Create the vector
vector_ex <- c(44, 30, 24, 32, 35)
## Add indexes 
vector_ex_indexed <- cbind( seq_along(vector_ex), vector_ex)

as.data.frame(vector_ex_indexed) %>%
  rename(Index = V1) 

  Index vector_ex
1     1        44
2     2        30
3     3        24
4     4        32
5     5        35
```

I would like to find the **first** minimum value of `vector_ex` taking into account the order of the Index and the **first** maximum value of `vector_ex` just after the index attached to the minimum.

For example in this case I want to identify - with dplyr:

- the first pair `Index` & `vector_ex` with the minimum value is:

  ```
  Index vector_ex
  3     3        24
  ```
- the first pair `Index` & `vector_ex` with the maximum value is:

  ```
  Index vector_ex
  5     5        35
  ```

Comment: Please explain more precisely the interplay of Index and your vector. With your example data, it is completely unclear why the first maximum value is 5 / 35 and not 1/44. So do you want to get the maximum/minimum of vector_ex or the Index? Or some combination? Or the min/max of vector x by Index group? Or something else?

Comment: the first minimum given the order of Index would be 24 at index 3; the first subsequent max (after index 3) would be 35 at 5. I would look for the first local minimum and its index and the first maximum after that index. In this way I would get the maximum difference given minimum and maximum given the order of the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
    slice(which.min(vector_ex):n()) %>%
    slice(c(1, which.max(vector_ex)))

  Index vector_ex
1     3        24
2     5        35
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be with `filter`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(vector_ex == min(vector_ex) |
         vector_ex == max(vector_ex[Index > Index[which.min(vector_ex)]]))

  Index vector_ex
1     3        24
2     5        35
```